# Using Apply Function in R as alternative to Loop

Tags: r, loops, apply

Looking for help. I am looking to create a balance build whereby the start balance in each row is dependent on the end balance from the preceeding row. The End Balance in the preceeding row is a calculation:

End Balance = Start Balance + Payments - Spend - (Start Balance * Interset)

In reality, the calculation is dependent on numerous variables but in principle what I am looking to do is the same. I want to be able to retain the end balance from the preceeding row. I have successfully managed to do this using a loop but it is quite slow and I would like to understand what I have done wrong when trying to replicate the same output but using the apply function. Any help would be amazing.

Also I am new to Stack Overflow, so if I have not posted in this in the right format then it would be great if you could let me know what I should have done differently.

```
ToB           <- c(0:5)
Spend         <- c(0,1000,50,50,50,50)
Payment       <- c(0,0,100,150,150,150)
Interest      <- c(0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0,0.05) 
End_Balance <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
Start_Balance <- rep(0, length(ToB))
Interest_Calc <- rep(0,6)
row <- 0

# initialise End Balance and Start balance
df               <- data.frame(ToB, Spend, Payment, Interest, Interest_Calc, Start_Balance, End_Balance)    

#EXISTING SOLUTION
# populate the remaining balances
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){

  df$Start_Balance[i] <- df$End_Balance[i - 1]
  df$Interest_Calc[i] <- df$End_Balance[i - 1] *Interest[i]
  df$End_Balance[i]   <- df$Start_Balance[i] + df$Payment[i] - df$Spend[i] + df$End_Balance[i - 1] *Interest[i]
  }


#ATTEMPT AT NEW SOLUTION USING APPLY
temp4 <- sapply(2:nrow(df), function (i) {

  df$Start_Balance[i] <- df$End_Balance[i - 1]
  df$Interest_Calc[i] <- df$End_Balance[i - 1] *Interest[i]
  df$End_Balance[i]   <- df$Start_Balance[i] + df$Payment[i] - df$Spend[i] + df$End_Balance[i - 1] *Interest[i]
})
```

Comment: You won't be able to use apply for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dason. Are you aware of another function/ alternative that would retain the start balance and provide a more efficient method than a loop?

Comment: Hi Silver, thanks for trying. What I want to produce is the End Balance output from the first example. Perhaps apply isnt the best technique for this as the others have mentioned as it produces a single vector, whereas I want to manipulate the values in the data frame.

Comment: Sorry, I see your problem. I give another try.

Comment: I tried `map` function and it works for all the row ( I run it over one function) but I was surprising the output are the same for all rows. I just try to help you. So, just have a look at `map` function from `purr` package.

Comment: Simply changing a for-loop into an apply-family function usually doesn't give you much in terms of speed improvement. In either case, apply will be clumsy here as it is meant for loops that are parallel rather than sequential, i.e. each calculation does not depend on the output of the last one.

Comment: @Silver_80 unfortunately, map will have the same issue as apply, i.e. it is not meant for sequential calculations. See e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals under "Loops that should be left as is".

Comment: Please see the answer.

Comment: Thanks niclas. Do you think there is an alternative solution or in this instance do I have to settle for a loop?